# Gradle sonarqube plugin fails with "Incompatible version 1007" with gradle version 2.13

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

We recently upgraded our gradle to version 2.13 (the latest at the time of this writing).  We are using the sonarqube plugin calling it via "gradlew clean test sonarqube".  Before the upgrade, everything was working fine with Sonar.

After we upgraded to version 2.13, we get the following error "Incompatible version 1007" and it looks like an incompatibility with the gradle jacoco plugin.  We are currently using version 2.0.1 of the sonarqube plugin and we also tried the sonarRunner plugin as well which fails with the same error.  Has anybody else run into this and how did you resolve it?

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
}


4:06:55.845 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
14:06:55.845 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Indicee-BI-API-Java-Library_platform_team/workspace/build/jacoco/test.exec
14:06:55.845 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:06:55.846 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
14:06:55.846 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.

14:06:55.852 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incompatible version 1007.
14:06:55.852 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readHeader(ExecutionDataReader.java:127)
14:06:55.852 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readBlock(ExecutionDataReader.java:107)
14:06:55.852 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.read(ExecutionDataReader.java:87)
14:06:55.853 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoOverallSensor.loadSourceFiles(JaCoCoOverallSensor.java:124)
14:06:55.853 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 95 more
```

Comment: Which version of JaCoCo is used to produce the report and which version of the sonarqube java plugin is used ?

Comment: In our gradle file, we never specified the jacoco plugin version so it is the default that comes with version 2.13 of gradle.  The sonarqube plugin version is above version 2.0.1, the latest at the time of this writing.

Comment: The only plugin version we explicitly specify is the sonarqube plugin.

Comment: The following are all the plugins that we incorporate:

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

Comment: FYI, gradle version 2.13 explicitly specified a breaking change from jacoco (https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes#jacoco-version-upgrade-to-0.7.6).  There is a workaround but we've upgraded our Jenkins environments to the latest Jacoco plugin already to account for this so the workaround won't help.  We didn't find out about the Sonar problems until later as they are a separate build step.

Comment: What is the version of the sonar java plugin installed on your sonarqube server ?

Comment: Will have to check.  Where is that configured where I can check?

Comment: I found it.  Version 3.3

Comment: You may want to ugprade to latest version (3.13.1) because this has been fixed in 3.4 : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1091

Comment: So is the error we're reporting based on the gradlew sonarqube plugin communicating with the SonarQube server we're running and the error is generated from the Sonarqube server itself and not gradle?

Answer (score 1):

The Sonar plugin upgrade for Java to 3.13.1 worked.  Thank you.